# How to implement ListActivity with icon in ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-actionbar

When I use `MainActivity extends ListActivity` this happens:

[image]

If I use `MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity` this happens:

[image]

I verified when I changed theme of `Theme.AppCompat` to `android:Theme.Holo` for ListActivity this happens, but I can't find a theme with support for this!

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Try to use Toolbar instead ActionBar if you are using it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your problem correctly, you want your `MainActivity` to extend `ListActivity`, but you also want your app to make use of the `AppCompat` support library?

If so, it would be quite straightforward to create your own `ListActivityCompat` class that extends `AppCompatActivity`, using the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/ListActivity.java#ListActivity) for `ListActivity` as a guide, It isn't an especially long file, and most of it you should be able to paste in verbatim.

Comment: Thanks, i created my custom ListView inside the MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity and this work.